# Incorrect syntax ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

I’m very new to ASP.net and have been following a few video tutorials to build a log in page. I successfully created my registration page fine that enters details into my table within the database fine however I can't get my log in page to work =/.I’ve been at this for a few hours and am not sure if any of you can help but it's worth a shot. The IDE I am using is visual studio (latest version).

I am getting the following error (clicking the image will give a closer view, but you probably already know that): 
[image]

the error changes depending on who I try to log on as for example the above error was returned when trying to log in as john, the below error was returned trying to log in as admin.

[image]

shown below is my code used behind the log in button:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration; 

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string checkuser = "select count(*) from [Table] where [Login]'" + Loginbox.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    conn.Close();
    if (temp == 1)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string CheckPasswordQuery = "select Password from [Table] where [Login]='" + Loginbox.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand Passcom = new SqlCommand(CheckPasswordQuery, conn);
        string password = Passcom.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ","");

        if (password == Passwordbox.Text)
        {
            Session["New"] = Passwordbox.Text; 
            Response.Write("Password is correct");


        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Wrong password");

        }
    }
    else {

        Response.Write("User name does not exist");


    }
    }


}
```

Shown below is the form page view, which runs perfectly fine, the error gets returned when the log in button is pressed.

[image]

Shown below is the table definition:

[image]

And shown below is the data contained within the table:

[image]

Thank you all for your time and I appreciate any input any of you have to help solve this.

Comment: Obligatory [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) warning. Use parameterized queries (and you may also see your error).

Comment: Just can confirm what the others say, thats one of the most unsecure ways to validate a login ;-) Have a look here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q

Comment: Oh yeah I gathered it’s awfully insecure, I’m sorry it’s my first page I’m just trying to learn the basics, it won’t be actually used for anything a promise you. If it was you guys could have some fun exploiting it.

Comment: And what has all that posting to do with the error: This is not an asp.net issue - this is a simple C# error, you can remove all the crap around it and nail it down to a couple of lines of pure C# and SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have invalid syntax in your query. Please note that while many tutorials may show you to query like this, it's very insecure. You should use parameters. However, for the sake of this answer, you forgot the equal sign:

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) from [Table] where [Login] = '" + Loginbox.Text + "'";
```

Comment: Please show how to use sql parameterization, as others might come into this and use this type of injection.

Comment: Another answer already shows this now, and it IS a safer bet.

Comment: Omg how could I have missed that :( Hours I have been staring at this, so sorry about that but thank you so much. and yeah I gathered it would be terribly unsecure I have a lot to learn, it's my first login page so I don't really know what I am doing, it's just experimenting I promise you that it won't be properly hosted.

Comment: @ceefax12 Instead of staring, read a book about basic debugging techniques. Using a debugger (like in visual studio) and running through the code step by step would help you to find the line. And look at the SQL you send. Oh, and READ THE ERROR MESSAGE. Copy/paste/staring will never make you better. You must learn to use a debugger. And learn how to isolate an error - all your posting is just irrelevant crap, it runs down to 2-3 lines around the SQL. You should be able to see that - train this.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is incorrect, but it is actually safer if you parameterize it to avoid sql injection

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) from [Table] where [Login] = @user";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
com.Parameters.Add("@user", Loginbox.Text);
...
```

Comment: Thank you :), after I’m done I will try implement it this way I’m just trying to get a working page for now though :) I know it's pretty badly insecure but I won't be using it for anything don't worry it's just to experiment.